# i'm running into some animation code that has worked in the past but currently is not executing

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have some code that has worked for me in the past but is currently not executing.

I honestly don't think the problem is in the Javascript but instead is either in the HTML or CSS. After all, I just copied and pasted the code and changed what was needed but I think I made a mistake in the HTML or CSS.

I just don't know where or if it is even something in them or if it's just my lack of experience with coding. I'll get to the code itself now.

```js
if (moveKey.key === 's') {
  $("div").animate({
    top: "150px"
  });
}
```

```css
.sign {
  position: absolute;
  color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  left: 10px;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 400px;
  font-size: 100px;
  color: red;
}

h2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 400px;
  top: 130px;
  font-size: 50px;
}

h3 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 480px;
  top: 132px;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Hello</div>
<h2>and</h2>
<h3>welcome</h3>
<div id="sign" class="sign"></div>
```

[and here's a link to the fiddle if you want it.](https://jsfiddle.net/Gamebit/hrLjmaf0/124/)

Comment: What is `movekey`? Where is it defined? That's the issue in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I've added an event listener around your code so clicking 's' would work.

```js
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(moveKey) {
  if (moveKey.key === 's') {
    $("div").animate({
      top: "150px"
    });
  }
})
```

```css
.sign {
  position: absolute;
  color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  left: 10px;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 400px;
  font-size: 100px;
  color: red;
}

h2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 400px;
  top: 130px;
  font-size: 50px;
}

h3 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 480px;
  top: 132px;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Hello</div>
<h2>and</h2>
<h3>welcome</h3>
<div id="sign" class="sign"></div>
```